# How to copy the GRUB menu to another disk whilst keeping the original

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, ssd

I tried to install Ubuntu (20.04) directly to a USB key for a friend to try out Ubuntu. I did the install using my Ubuntu (19.10) system to do so.

All went well installing to the USB key and it boots up as expected. Unfortunately, it seems to have wiped the GRUB menu from my original (19.10) SSD and my system will now only boot with the USB key in so I can select 19.10.

Is there a way to copy the GRUB menu from the USB back onto my SSD so I can boot my 19.10 SSD installation as normal whilst still being able to boot the USB independently in another system?

I have very little experience with GRUB or how the boot process works so sorry if this is a stupidly obvious question.

Comment: Try booting the SSD using the USB key, once booted remove the key and run `sudo update-grub`.